# For my self assessment do I need to fill out both the Capital Gains Summary and Tax Return?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, capital-gain, capital-gains-tax

I received a documents through the post from the HMRC, a Capital Gains Summary and a Tax Return. The thing is I just want to tell them my gains/losses in shares using the Capital Gains Summary document, the Tax Return doesn't seem to apply as it has other taxes and items, such as taxes for self employed people (which I am not).

Do I have to fill out the Capital Gains Summary as part of my self assessment? Or do the HMRC require me to fill out the Tax Return too but just keep it blank for all the things that don't apply (i.e most of them apart from the CGT box)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to fill out the whole tax return, because the rate of tax payable on your capital gains depends on your total taxable income. And in any case, if you have capital gains you probably have other income of *some* kind that's not fully accounted for in your PAYE code.

Comment: Ok, however in the pages on the Tax Return, it has CGT, Charities etc. I am employeed and don't have a business, so I assume my employer just does the normal income tax for me and I just tick the CGT box on the Tax Return and leave the rest blank? Is that right?

Comment: No, you have to enter your PAYE tax paid by your employer -- just copy the figures off your P60 for the relevant year. You also have to enter any interest or dividend income received (and you surely must have some if you have capital gains).